# Can I replace an LM741 op amp with an AD620 op amp in my circuit?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, comparator

I have a voltage comparator circuit (shown below.) Can I replace the opamp with an AD620 op amp? My lab has mostly AD620 op amps.

[image: this is a voltage comparator circuit diagram]

Comment: Why don't you just try it? What makes you think that you might not be able to replace the 741s?

Comment: The opamps seem to be powered by 2V while one of the inputs receives 3V. It is not going to be easy to find one that works in these conditions. Maybe you could take a step back and edit the question to describe what problem are you trying to solve and with which contraints.

Comment: You're also, in effect, driving your opamp outputs to ground via two diodes.

Comment: How does this circuit even work with 741s?

Comment: This circuit won't do what you expect . If you want to define your expectations or input + output specs, a better design can be had that won't drain the battery so much and will work below 2V. But you need to define these specs

Comment: If V2 is 3 volts (as it appears to be) the circuit will not finction with an LM741. Can you show where the circuit came from? [LM741 data sheet here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Texas%20Instruments%20PDFs/LM741_Series_Rev_July_2016.pdf). You need about 8V supply V+-V- (+4, -4, gnd) to guarantee operation - and you'll get zero output swing with those voltages.  Something is wrong with your circuit.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until there's some details added about the circuit. Driving a 741 with 2 volts is extremely out of specifications, so either the circuit never worked, or it's taking advantage of the exact internal structure of the 741 in some clever way - information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

An AD620 is not an 'opamp' - it is an 'Instrumentation Amplifier'. These are similar, but not the same. While similar, in general they cannot replace each other.

Note the AD620 is not pin compatible with the 741. At a minimum it would need a gain-setting resistor.

The 741 is quite old (and robust for lab use). Try a TL081.

Comment: AD620 ain't no spring chicken.

Comment: TL081 needs 7V min for power and won't work at 3 or even 2V , try again

Comment: No, the TL081 is 5V; the 081H is 4.5 V; the 741 is (was) about similar. The OP's Q is not clear and his circuit won't work, so refining that V isn't that critical now.

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answer says, AD620 is an instrumentation amplifier (in-amp), not an op-amp. In general it cannot be substituted for an op-amp. (It typically takes 2 or 3 op-amps to substitute for an in-amp)

It looks like you're trying to build a window comparator. You should probably try to use a comparator for this function rather than an op-amp or in-amp. Although many op-amps will work as comparators, a purpose-built comparator will probably perform better. Also, comparators are readily available with open-drain outputs, eliminating the need for your external diodes.

An in-amp (like AD620) is absolutely wrong for this because it does not have the very high gain of an op-amp or comparator.

Answer (score 2):

That’s not a very nice circuit. The transistor base current is only limited by the op-amp internal current limit and the 2V supply voltage is very much inadequate for an LM741. Also the output swing of the amplifier may make it dubious whether the transistor is on or off when it should be off. And the input voyage range of the 741 (wrt the power supply rails) is also being violated at both ends.

I would be surprised if this circuit did much other than fairly rapidly drain batteries.

You could redesign this a bit and use an LM324, but as-is it needs work and swapping in an instrumentation amplifier that has similar issues (4.6V minimum supply voltage, for just one example) is not likely to prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose components that work within the 2 thresholds for Vcm input and Vbat.
2. These are called (low-side) **voltage comparators** ( with PNP inputs ) and the inputs work down to 0V=V-.
3. Don't use Op Amps or INA's as most are not "Rail-to-rail" input types
4. Comparators usually have NPN Open Collector outputs which can  replace your "diode OR logic"  for your Fault condition for low or high voltage input.
5. **Scale down ** both your reference voltage down AND the battery voltage , i.e. don't connect direct unless it is a high side comparator with NPN inputs (less common)
6. Since input currents are low, you can scale up your resistor ratios to draw less power.  Consider the max input current as an equiv. R load for errors.
7. read the [datasheet specs for the KA339xx part](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/d66cli4en8/FAIRS31632-1.pdf) which you may have or similar in stock.